# ejabberd XMPP connection failed using strophejs

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I am trying to run [THIS XMPP JS](https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp/tree/master/ch03) code using ejabberd on server side. Here is my connection code:

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    console.log("connect "+JSON.stringify(data));
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:5280/http-bind");

    conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
        console.log("status"+status);
        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        }
    });

    Hello.connection = conn;
});
```

I am getting `status = 1`. and after few time later it starts keep showing :
`Uncaught Error: 11, flXHR::abort(): Failed, The abort() call failed to complete.`

My ejabberd is running on `http://localhost:5280/admin/` and `admin@ejab` is admin user.

Here is full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Strophe.js Basic Example</title>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../strophe.js'></script>
<!--    <script src='scripts/flXHR.js'></script>
    <script src='scripts/strophe.flxhr.js'></script>-->
    <script src='basic.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='login' style='text-align: center'>
      <form name='cred'>
        <label for='jid'>JID:</label>
        <input type='text' id='jid'>
        <label for='pass'>Password:</label>
        <input type='password' id='pass'>
        <input type='button' id='connect' value='connect'>
      </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id='log'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`basic.js`

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://localhost:5222/http-bind';
var connection = null;

function log(msg) 
{
    $('#log').append('<div></div>').append(document.createTextNode(msg));
}

function rawInput(data)
{
    log('RECV: ' + data);
}

function rawOutput(data)
{
    log('SENT: ' + data);
}

function onConnect(status)
{
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
    log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
    log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
    log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
    log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    log('Strophe is connected.');
    connection.disconnect();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
    connection.rawInput = rawInput;
    connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;

    $('#connect').bind('click', function () {
    var button = $('#connect').get(0);
    if (button.value == 'connect') {
        button.value = 'disconnect';

        connection.connect($('#jid').get(0).value,
                   $('#pass').get(0).value,
                   onConnect);
    } else {
        button.value = 'connect';
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    });
});
```

ouput is :

```
Strophe is connecting.
SENT: <body rid='745165534' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='ejab' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

Comment: Which version of ejabberd server are you using ? It seems you have cross domain issue, but this is automatically handled on latest versions, so I guess you are using an old ejabberd version.

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: chrome Version 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

status = 1 means connecting. It mostly means BOSH server cannot be reached.

Type in 
http://localhost:5280/http-bind/
at Chrome to see if you can really reach the BOSH server.

If your server is really host at localhost (your computer where hello.html stored), you can comment out the 
flXHR.js and strophe.flxhr.js at hello.html's header as they are for cross domain access.

e.g. hello.html at your desktop and using a domain(xmpp server) that host at another computer which are not allowed by Chrome due to cross domain access security already.

If both hello.html and xmpp server are located at the same computer, it won't have cross domain issue.

Anyway, these 2 files seem not able to overcome the cross domain access limit set by Chrome browser a few years back. Use Chrome's parameter "--disable-web-security" can provide cross domain access for test.

Lastly, at Chrome browser, right click to select "Inspect Element" -> Network, reload the hello.html and login to check those http-bind access. They should give hint on what goes wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question that will help you how i am going. I tried it in mozilla and output is like `Strophe is connecting.
SENT: <body rid='745165534' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='ejab' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>`   When i browse `http://localhost:5280/http-bind/` it show me page saying `ejabberd mod_http_bindAn implementation of XMPP over BOSH (XEP-0206)This web page is only informative. To use HTTP-Bind you need a Jabber/XMPP client that supports it.`